# filter column + insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
   TABLE1:

   field1  |   field2   |   field3   
     1          5             aaa
     2          10            bbb
     3          10            ccc
     4          10            ddd
     5          10            eee
     6          6             fff
     7          7             ggg

 TABLE2:

 will have the insert of all values that contain in field2 >= 2 equals value
 so in this case it should be like this:

 TABLE2:

    field1  |   field2   |   field3   
      2          10            bbb
      3          10            ccc
      4          10            ddd
      5          10            eee
```

how can I know whats values have the >= 2 same name? and make this insert?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want the second table to have all duplicates (relative to field2) in the first table.

```
select field1, field2, field3
into table2
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by field2) as cnt
      from table1 t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

This creates the second table using `select into`.  If it already exists, use `insert . . . select` instead.